# Programa twoSum de leet code en Python

Tags: lista, bucle-for, python-3.8

Intentando realizar este problema en Python: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/
...me surge la siguiente duda... Hasta ahora el código que llevo es este.

```
class Solution:
def twoSum(self, nums, target: int):
    for i in nums:
        for j in nums:
            if i + j == target and nums.index(i) != nums.index(j):
                print (nums.index(i), nums.index(j))
```

Concretamente el problema es que al iterar con los bucles for la lista que se ingresa, suponiendo que la lista tiene 2 elementos iguales, solo se itera el primer elemento, por las propias características de las listas, pero necesito iterar todos los elementos aunque estén repetidos. ¿Hay alguna solución o estoy enfocando mal el problema?

Comment: porque decis que un for no itera todos los elementos?

Comment: Porque si agregamos
print (nums.index(i), nums.index(j))
justo encima de la instrucción if el output es
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0

Comment: ehhh... y? no se entiende tu duda ni tu problema... ahora.. no se como es tu problema.. pero tus condiciones del if suena raro.. el target lo estas buscando como la suma de indices y no como la suma de valores?

Comment: ese print que te comenté demuestra que no se están iterando todos los valores de la lista ya que son iguales. No existe forma de crear un iterable que itere todos los valores aunque estén repetidos ? esa es mi duda concreta.

Comment: index devuelve el indice del primer valor cuyo valor es igual al que le pasaste. por eso preguntaba que tratas de hacer. creo que tu confusion es mas profunda.. leiste la documentacion??? https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Deberías tener cuidado con los datos que te están dando en el problema, si intentas hacer ese tipo de problema con una simple fuerza bruta no será para nada óptimo; es más, será muy lento y consumirá muchos recursos de tu PC. Ten en cuenta los Constraints que te especifican. Si aún así, deseas seguir con tu código, pues recuerda MUY LENTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá te pongo algunos ejemplos que quizás te puedan ser de utilidad. El último se ejecuta en O(n), pero el primero en O(n^2):

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum1(self, nums, target: int):
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
                if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]
        return "No existen elementos que sumen "+str(target)
    
    def twoSum2(self, nums, target: int):
        diccionario={}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            diferencia = target - nums[i]
            if diferencia in diccionario:
                return [diccionario[diferencia],i]
            else:
                diccionario[nums[i]] = i
        return "No existen elementos que sumen "+str(target)


solucion1 = Solution()

print("Primera solución:")
print(solucion1.twoSum1([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
print(solucion1.twoSum1([3, 2, 4], 6))
print(solucion1.twoSum1([3,3], 6))

print("\nSegunda solución:")
print(solucion1.twoSum2([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
print(solucion1.twoSum2([3, 2, 4], 6))
print(solucion1.twoSum2([3, 3], 6))
```

El resultado en consola se muestra:

```
Primera solución:
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[0, 1]

Segunda solución:
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[0, 1]
```